# Issue in testing the performance of populating a Seq vs a List in Scala

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I've been trying to understand more about the rationale in choosing either a Seq or a List in Scala, to aid this I am trying to create a simple timed example where I create an instance of each, both populated with the same number of elements - see below.

```
object SeqVsList extends App with LazyLogging {

  private val numberOfElements = 1234567

  // whichever of these is run first takes the most amount of time
  populateSeq()
  populateList()

  def populateSeq(): Unit = {
    val seqStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val aSeq = Seq.fill(numberOfElements)("foo")
    logger.info(s"Populating Seq took ${System.currentTimeMillis() - seqStartTime} ms")
  }

  def populateList(): Unit = {
    val listStartTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
    val aList = List.fill(numberOfElements)("bar")
    logger.info(s"Populating List took ${System.currentTimeMillis() - listStartTime} ms")
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having (as defined in my comment in the code) is that the example does not accurately represent which one is quickest to populate all elements, instead whichever of the methods I call first is always the slowest.

I imagine there's something going on behind the scenes such as loading a bunch of objects into memory at runtime which slows down the first of the two methods? If someone could help me shed some light on this I'd be very grateful.

Comment: `Seq.fill` and `List.fill` - are _exactly the same_ (it is the same function), as you could easily see if you looked at the source. The first call (actually the first few calls) will always be slower than subsequent ones because of things like memory allocation, class loading, JIT, etc. This is known as "warm up".

Comment: [This link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html) shows the performance characteristics of the various Scala collections. Use this table to decide which collection type to use.

Comment: Thank you both, yes I understand that warm up will take a bit of time/resource and thank you for the documentation link however the purpose of this is to be able to manifest the performance difference in a simple piece of code. Perhaps I'm missing something but being that fill is being run independently for the Seq and the List I was not expecting this to impact one more than the other, can you explain how this might happen to two independent fill method calls?

Comment: Benchmarking the JVM should not be done in such a _naive_ way (not intentions to sound rude). You have to take in mind **Garbage Collection** cycles, the **JIT**, the **JVM** warn up period, etc. There are toolkits for doing this which are aware of all of that and more. - Other problems with your test are: 1) The default implementation of a `Seq` is a `List`. 2) `fill` is not a good test case, since it is internally optimized and that it is not commonly used, better tests would be to build a `List` and a `Seq` manually on a recursive function or on a `foldLetf`.

Comment: Also, complementing Tim's link, see [this](http://www.lihaoyi.com/post/BenchmarkingScalaCollections.html) for an empirical approach.

Comment: Ah fantastic thank you Luis that is the explanation I'm looking for, I will aim to populate it manually instead then - I was just hoping I could create something ultra simple to demonstrate the difference

Comment: Additionally, the discussion about `Seq` VS `List` Is more related to having it as a parameter or return type. Because, if you have a `Seq` you do not know what you had, as such, you do not know what you can _safely_ do on it. But creating a `Seq` will (as of today) return a `List`. As such, IMHO, creating a `Seq` does not make sense.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to proof the idea of equality Seq and List by some benchmark test with **sbt-jmh**:

```
package bmks

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit

import org.openjdk.jmh.annotations.{Benchmark, OutputTimeUnit}

@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
class TestBenchmark {

  @Benchmark
  def seq(): Seq[String] =
    Seq.fill(1234567)("foo")

  @Benchmark
  def list(): Seq[String] =
    List.fill(1234567)("foo")
}
```

run it with:

```
$ sbt 
$ sbt:benchmarks> jmh:run -i 20 -wi 10 -f1 -t1
```

and got:

```
sbt:benchmarks> jmh:run -i 20 -wi 10 -f1 -t1
[info] Compiling 1 Scala source to /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/benchmarks_2.12-1.0.jar ...
Processing 1 classes from /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/classes with "reflection" generator
Writing out Java source to /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/src_managed/jmh and resources to /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/resource_managed/jmh
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Compiling 6 Java sources to /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/classes ...
[info] Done compiling.
[info] Packaging /Volumes/AuroraHD/DEV/scala/benchmarks/target/scala-2.12/benchmarks_2.12-1.0-jmh.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info] Running (fork) org.openjdk.jmh.Main -i 20 -wi 10 -f1 -t1
[info] # JMH version: 1.21
[info] # VM version: JDK 1.8.0_161, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.161-b12
[info] # VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
[info] # VM options: <none>
[info] # Warmup: 10 iterations, 10 s each
[info] # Measurement: 20 iterations, 10 s each
[info] # Timeout: 10 min per iteration
[info] # Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
[info] # Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
[info] # Benchmark: bmks.TestBenchmark.list
[info] # Run progress: 0.00% complete, ETA 00:10:00
[info] # Fork: 1 of 1
[info] # Warmup Iteration   1: 0.091 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   2: 0.111 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   3: 0.111 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   4: 0.113 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   5: 0.112 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   6: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   7: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   8: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   9: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration  10: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   1: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   2: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   3: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   4: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   5: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   6: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   7: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   8: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   9: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  10: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  11: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  12: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  13: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  14: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  15: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  16: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  17: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  18: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  19: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  20: 0.117 ops/ms
[info] Result "bmks.TestBenchmark.list":
[info]   0.115 ±(99.9%) 0.001 ops/ms [Average]
[info]   (min, avg, max) = (0.114, 0.115, 0.117), stdev = 0.001
[info]   CI (99.9%): [0.114, 0.116] (assumes normal distribution)
[info] # JMH version: 1.21
[info] # VM version: JDK 1.8.0_161, Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, 25.161-b12
[info] # VM invoker: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java
[info] # VM options: <none>
[info] # Warmup: 10 iterations, 10 s each
[info] # Measurement: 20 iterations, 10 s each
[info] # Timeout: 10 min per iteration
[info] # Threads: 1 thread, will synchronize iterations
[info] # Benchmark mode: Throughput, ops/time
[info] # Benchmark: bmks.TestBenchmark.seq
[info] # Run progress: 50.00% complete, ETA 00:05:01
[info] # Fork: 1 of 1
[info] # Warmup Iteration   1: 0.094 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   2: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   3: 0.118 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   4: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   5: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   6: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   7: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   8: 0.115 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration   9: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] # Warmup Iteration  10: 0.117 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   1: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   2: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   3: 0.089 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   4: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   5: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   6: 0.118 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   7: 0.116 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   8: 0.118 ops/ms
[info] Iteration   9: 0.118 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  10: 0.117 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  11: 0.117 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  12: 0.107 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  13: 0.111 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  14: 0.113 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  15: 0.113 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  16: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  17: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  18: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  19: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Iteration  20: 0.114 ops/ms
[info] Result "bmks.TestBenchmark.seq":
[info]   0.114 ±(99.9%) 0.005 ops/ms [Average]
[info]   (min, avg, max) = (0.089, 0.114, 0.118), stdev = 0.006
[info]   CI (99.9%): [0.108, 0.119] (assumes normal distribution)
[info] # Run complete. Total time: 00:10:02
[info] REMEMBER: The numbers below are just data. To gain reusable insights, you need to follow up on
[info] why the numbers are the way they are. Use profilers (see -prof, -lprof), design factorial
[info] experiments, perform baseline and negative tests that provide experimental control, make sure
[info] the benchmarking environment is safe on JVM/OS/HW level, ask for reviews from the domain experts.
[info] Do not assume the numbers tell you what you want them to tell.
[info] Benchmark            Mode  Cnt  Score   Error   Units
[info] TestBenchmark.list  thrpt   20  0.115 ± 0.001  ops/ms
[info] TestBenchmark.seq   thrpt   20  0.114 ± 0.005  ops/ms
[success] Total time: 607 s, completed Apr 29, 2019 8:35:22 PM
```

**Conclusion: they are equal.**